# Ubuntu Studio default PulseAudio output device

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, ubuntu-studio, jack

I just installed Ubuntu Studio Controls over Kubuntu 20.04 LTS. I use 2 sound devices:

- Input: Soundboard through USB (is setup as JACKs master)
- Output: Internal PCI soundcard

I see that the new Ubuntu Studio Controls has an option to create a Pulseaudio bridge, but it can only be set to auto connect to "system:playback_" which in my case is the USB soundboard.

I was wondering if that default could be changed, perhaps in a config file somewhere to allow this automatic connection on login.

Here you can see the Auto Connect Option and my intended setup in Carla:

[image: Here you can see the Auto Connect Option and my intended setup in Carla]

Basically, I would need to reconfigure the "Auto Connect" option to SB,0,0-out which is the soundcard I use as an output

EDIT: I just checked back my [Ubuntu Studio 19.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv9xA.png) to see why it was working there and I just saw that there is an option "Default PulseAudio output device" that allows you to select the device to connect to automatically. Is that option removed for good? Is there any way to switch back to the old version?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a number of reasons, this had to be temporarily removed for the Focal Fossa release cycle. We plan on bringing the feature back in a future version (which has been [upstreamed](https://github.com/ovenwerks/studio-controls)). If you wish to have the latest version when it's ready, add the [Ubuntu Studio Backports PPA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/BackportsPPA).

Comment: I see... I'll setup a workaround with Carla or something in the meantime if it is a returning feature. Thanks a lot for your quick answer!